# Modal that displaying from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

How to display a modal popup that look like from a UITableViewCell (look like option ), which displaying a custom controller?

I'm trying to achieve something like contact app does ( see below ) :

[image]

Below is my current implementation, which only displaying common modal :

```
 TSCAliasViewController *V2 = [[TSCAliasViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
V2.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
V2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentModalViewController:V2 animated:YES];
V2.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 300);
V2.view.superview.center = self.formView.center;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [UIPopoverController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html). Currently it works on iPad only!